# Increasing performance of the perl code

Tags: performance, perl, matrix, hash

Following program runs fine but large data **takes infinite time.**
**INPUT.txt**  .    Actually, I have upto 1000 lines with from 1 upto 100 elements per line.

```
10  
6  
9  
7  
9 11  
3 4  
1 9  
5 12  
1 11  
5 11  
9 12  
10 5 8  
7 4 1
and so on...  
last: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 . . .any number of elements (100 in my case).
```

**matrix.txt**  (TAB DELIMIITED)

```
1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   
1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   1   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   
1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   0   1   1   1   1   0   1   0   0   1   1   
1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   
1   0   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   0   1   1   0   1   1   1   1   0   1   0   1   1   1   
1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   
1   0   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   0   0   1   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   1   1   
1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   
and so on....upto 25000 lines
```

**output.txt**
these are **sums** of elements in matrix.txt at index position taken from each line of INPUT.txt.
 actual sums may differ from this hypothetical sample output.

```
1   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   2   2   2   2   2 . . .columns upto number of lines in input.txt
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   2   2   2   2   2
1   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   2   2   2   2   2
1   1   1   0   1   0   0   1   1   2   2   2   2   2
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   2   2   2   2   2
1   1   1   0   1   0   1   1   1   1   2   2   2   2
1   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   2   2   2   2   2
1   1   1   1   1   0   0   1   1   1   2   2   2   2
0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   2   2   2   2   2
```

**code  :** have a look at the code it will help you understand what is happening.

```
use List::Util 'sum';
my @indexes = do {
    open my $fh, '<', "INPUT.txt";
    map { [map {$_ - 1} split ' '] } <$fh>
};
open my $infh, '<', "matrix.txt";
open OUT, '>', "output.txt";
while (<$infh>) {
    my @vals = split ' ';
    print OUT join('    ', map {sum(@vals[@$_])} @indexes), "\n";
}
close OUT;
```

**Is there any other way to accomplish this task in lesser time.**

File availability:
INPUT: https://www.dropbox.com/s/48ikhnfs7gzk8vm/input.txt?dl=0
MATRIX: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ebxi608eday9z1e/matrix.txt?dl=0

Comment: is there any way you can drop a link to your input.txt (and matrix.txt)

Comment: @osirisgothra
input: https://www.dropbox.com/s/48ikhnfs7gzk8vm/input.txt?dl=0

matrix: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ebxi608eday9z1e/matrix.txt?dl=0

Comment: Did you profile your program? If not, try [Devel::NYTProf](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::NYTProf) to find out what your bottlenecks are. Also, your problem seems to be a fitting task for [PDL](https://metacpan.org/pod/PDL). It is hard to read into, it might be worth the while if you see similar tasks coming up ahead. It has `Module::Compile` as a dependency and the most recent version of that module fails its test on many systems. try installing like this: `cpanm Module::Compile@0.30` to get a version that works on most systems.

Comment: Are the lines in `matrix.txt` fixed size?

Comment: @PatrickJ.S. yeah fixed size.

Answer (score 3):

One thing to look at/try is the math and matrix oriented modules on cpan. Some of them use native code (are c based extensions of perl) which *should* be faster. Here's a (dated) primer on them-

http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=284324

Answer (score 2):

I made a PDL version which exploits the fact that you're essentially performing a matrix multiplication with a selection vector. This version assumes the matrix will always have 100 elements in it. If that's not true, you have to change the zeroes call accordingly.

It runs about twice as fast for input of size (1 000 x 100) (25 000 x 100). Reading the entire matrix into memory and then processing results in the same runtime, though it might be faster if you enable parallelism. In case you were wondering what an approximate runtime floor would be, an optimized c version runs about 4 times faster than that (8x the original). All times are of course tied to my machine, but I would expect similar ratios on most computers. I also make no claim that my PDL is optimal since I used this as an excuse to learn it.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use PDL;

my $indexes = PDL::long(do {
    open(my $fh, '<', 'INPUT.txt') or die;
    # The first map is if you allow duplicates in the index list (i.e. 2 2 is a valid row)
    # map { my $p = zeroes(100); $p->slice($_)++ foreach (map {$_ - 1} split /\t/); $p } <$fh>
    map { zeroes(100)->dice([map {$_ - 1} split /\t/])++ } <$fh>
})->xchg(0, 1);

open(my $input, '<', 'matrix.txt') or die;
open(my $output, '>', 'output.txt') or die;

while(<$input>) {
    my $vals = PDL::long(split(/\t/));
    print $output join("\t", ($vals x $indexes)->list) . "\n";
}
```

Comment: Some memory (and possibly space) changes: The first `PDL::long` should be an `indx` and for the second, you could actually get away with `short`.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! I didn't see indx in the online documentation, though I can see that it is the correct type now that I know of it. As for the short, I wasn't sure what the data range on his matrix was (I suppose really I should have been using Double based on the lack of knowledge, but since everything was just a bit in the sample I defaulted to integer)

Comment: Well really it should be that the two datatypes should match. The only thing being actually used as an indx is the array being passed into dice, after that it's a counter (that I know would be a byte at most, but since I'm multiplying it by the second dataset it should match to reduce type-casting)

Comment: Yeah, I played around a bit with `PDL` and this problem as well under the assumption that the matrix's values are just ones and zeroes and it didn't have much success in speedups (because of the typecasting, I'd guess). The only other thing I found is that you could then replace the `<$input>` with a `read`, or setting `$/` to an integer reference, since you know the exact size, saves you a little searching, and you can read more lines at ones.

Answer (score 0):

Would you have a better idea as to which 'bit' is costing you the performance?

Reason I ask - there's a sort of holy trinity of performance bottlenecks:

- CPU - the actual operations being done on the processor
- 'Active' memory (size of memory profile vs. available RAM and how much you're reshuffling).
- IO - transferring data to/from disk.

You can often trade off one against another - gain CPU efficiency via creating lookup tables, that kind of thing.

Operations such as map are ones that I start to look closer at - things like map/sort/grep are very powerful, but have a potential to be using a less than optimal algorithm.

If you're CPU bound you can try and use multithreading or forking to increase CPU access. On the face of it, it *looks* like you've no dependencies on your processing of 'matrix.txt' (e.g. each line is standalone) so it may be a good candidate for parallelism.

I'd be thinking in terms of using Parallel::ForkManager to wrap that `while` loop. The downside of doing this is that you'll then have a non deterministic ordering of your output, which'd need addressing.

So starter for 10 might be:

```
use List::Util 'sum';
use Data::Dumper;
use Fcntl qw(:flock);

use Parallel::ForkManager;

my $mgr = Parallel::ForkManager->new(10);

my @indexes = do {
    open my $fh, '<', "INPUT.txt";
    map {
        [ map { $_ - 1 } split ' ' ]
    } <$fh>;
};
open my $infh,   '<', "matrix.txt";
open my $out_fh, '>', "output.txt";
while (<$infh>) {
    $mgr->start and next;
    my @vals = split ' ';
    my $output_line = join( '    ', map { sum( @vals[@$_] ) } @indexes ),
        "\n";
    {
        flock( $out_fh, LOCK_EX );
        print {$out_fh} $output_line;
    }
}
close $out_fh;
```

Note - this'll work, but you'll get a random output order, which is almost certainly not what you want. But it'll use 10 processors concurrently to do the 'join/map/sum' operation.

(Of course, if you're IO bound, this won't help any).

But for synchronising IO, I find threading is quite a good option:

```
 use warnings;
 use strict;

use List::Util 'sum';

use threads; 
use Thread::Queue;

my $line_q = Thread::Queue -> new(); 
my $output_q = Thread::Queue -> new(); 

my %line_output : shared; 

    my @indexes = do {
        open my $fh, '<', "INPUT.txt";
        map {
            [ map { $_ - 1 } split ' ' ]
        } <$fh>;
};


sub generate_output {
   while ( my $item = $line_q -> dequeue() ) {
   print "processing $item \n";
       my ( $line_num, @vals ) = split ( ' ', $item );           
       $output_q -> enqueue($line_num.":". join('    ', map {sum(@vals[@$_])} @indexes ). "\n");
   }
}

sub coalesce_output {
    open my $out_fh, '>', "output.txt";
    my $current_line = 0; 
    my %lines;
    while ( my $item = $output_q -> dequeue ) {
        my ( $line_num, $output_line ) = split ( ":", $item );
        if ( $line_num = $current_line ) { 
            print {$out_fh} $output_line;
            $current_line++; 
        }
        else {
           $lines{$line_num} = $output_line; 
        }
        while ( defined $lines{$current_line} ) {
            print {$out_fh} $lines{$current_line};
            delete $lines{$current_line};
            $current_line++;
        }
    }
}




open my $infh,   '<', "matrix.txt";

my @workers;
for ( 1..10 ) {
  push ( @workers, threads -> create ( \&generate_output ) ); 
}

threads -> create ( \&coalesce_output );

while (my $line = <$infh>) {
    $line_q -> enqueue ( "$.: $line" );
}

$line_q -> end();
foreach my $thr ( @workers ) {
  $thr -> join(); 
}

$output_q -> end();
```

For example. Spins off 10 'workers' to do the summing operations in parallel, and one 'output' thread to write the data in the right order.

So something like:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use List::Util 'sum';

use threads;
use Thread::Queue;

my $line_q   = Thread::Queue->new();
my $output_q = Thread::Queue->new();

my @indexes = do {
    open my $fh, '<', "INPUT.txt";
    map {
        [ map { $_ - 1 } split ' ' ]
    } <$fh>;
};


sub generate_output {
    while ( my $item = $line_q->dequeue() ) {

        #print "processing $item \n";
        my ( $line_num, @vals ) = split( ' ', $item );
        $output_q->enqueue( $line_num . ":"
                . join( '    ', map { sum( @vals[@$_] ) } @indexes )
                . "\n" );
    }
}

sub coalesce_output {
    open my $out_fh, '>', "output.txt";
    my $current_line = 1;
    my %lines;
    while ( my $item = $output_q->dequeue ) {

        my ( $line_num, $output_line ) = split( ":", $item );

        #     print "Got $line_num ($current_line) $item\n";
        if ( $line_num = $current_line ) {

            #   print "printing $current_line = $output_line\n";
            print {$out_fh} $output_line;
            $current_line++;
        }
        else {
            $lines{$line_num} = $output_line;
        }
        while ( defined $lines{$current_line} ) {

    #   print "printing  (while) $current_line = $lines{$current_line}\n";
            print {$out_fh} $lines{$current_line};
            delete $lines{$current_line};
            $current_line++;
        }
    }
}


open my $infh, '<', "matrix.txt";

my @workers;
for ( 1 .. 40 ) {
    push( @workers, threads->create( \&generate_output ) );
}

threads->create( \&coalesce_output );

while ( my $line = <$infh> ) {
    $line_q->enqueue("$. $line");
}

$line_q->end();
foreach my $thr (@workers) {
    $thr->join();
}

$output_q->end();
foreach my $thr ( threads -> list ) { $thr -> join(); }
```

Produces (+more):

```
 1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    2    2    2    2
 2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2
 2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2
 2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2
 2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    3    3
 3    3    3    3    3    3    3    3    3    3    3    3    3    3    3    3
 3    3    3    3    3    3    3    3    3    3    3    3    3    3    3    3
```

In the end though - it depends rather on what your limiting factor is.

Running a quick and dirty test gives

```
Started at 1417007048,
finished at 1417007064
Took:16s
```

Vs.

```
Started at 1417007118
finished at 1417007161
Took:43s
```

(I haven't validated the outputs of both exhaustively)